# How to add a menu items for tiles menu in W10

Tags: xaml, uwp

How to add a menu items for tiles menu in W10 using UWP? Preferably through xaml

[image: Tiles menu image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Feature allowing custom menu items is called **jump lists** and it works both on live tiles and on the task bar buttons. The best way to learn about it is from the official [sample on GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/JumpList) and from [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.startscreen.jumplist).

A very simple jumplist could be created like this:

```cs
var jumpList = await Windows.UI.StartScreen
  .jumpList.LoadCurrentAsync();
jumpList.Items.Clear();

JumpListItem sampleItem = JumpListItem
  .CreateWithArguments("item", "Do something");

jumpList.Items.Add(sampleItem);
```

If you want to display **recently opened files** (as is the case in the screenshot), you must create a file extension association for your app and store accessed files in the Most recently used list. This can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/how-to-track-recently-used-files-and-folders) and is managed using the `Windows.Storage.AccessCache.StorageApplicationPermissions.MostRecentlyUsedList` class.